I'm getting a 403 error with Swagger in my Spring Boot app
I've an API with spring boot and I'd like to add swagger, but everytime I want to acesss to
"/swagger-ui/", "/swagger-ui.html"

I get a 403 error but when I access to /v3/api-docs I'm able to see the JSON file
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private  JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    @Autowired
    private  MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                        .requestMatchers("/movies/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                        .requestMatchers("/clients/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                        .requestMatchers("/rents/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/auth/**").permitAll() // Allow Swagger
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/mappings/**").permitAll()
                        //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}

as you can see I tried to add swagger-ui path with permitAll() but it doesn't work

Newer versions of swagger use /swagger-ui/index.html instead of /swagger-ui.html. Have you tried that?

@sweintritt Would the status code not be 404 then rather than 403?

Yeah it would. Have your tried to remove all matchers and permitt all acccess to /**?
